# How to check if a std::async task is finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++11, std

In my graphics application I want to generate a batch meshes in another thread. Therefore I asynchrony call the member function using `std::async`.

```
task = async(launch::async, &Class::Meshing, this, Data(...));
```

In my update loop I try to check if the thread is ready. If yes, I will send the mesh to the video card and start the next thread. If not, I will skip these operations.

```
#include <future>
using namespace std;

class Class
{
public:
    void Update()
    {
        if(task.finished()) // this method does not exist
        {
            Data data = task.get();
            // ...
            task = async(launch::async, &Class::Meshing, this, Data(/* ... */));
        }
    }

private:
    struct Data
    {
        // ...
    };
    future<Data> task;
    Data Meshing(Data data)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

How can I check if the asynchrony thread finished without stucking in the update function?

Comment: I think the closest approximation would be to use `std::future::wait_for` with the smallest duration you can manage.

Comment: It seems the _standard `future`_ didn't inherit the _Boost `future`_ `is_ready` member function, that's a shame...

Comment: I'd really recommend [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism) where Herb Sutter goes over where async futures stand now, what their limitations are, and some possible ways to overcome them.

Comment: @SeanCline: And I would like to point out that _boost::future_ already implements some of those extensions, like `wait_for_any` and `wait_for_all`. We are only missing `then`...

Comment: @K-ballo: and, `when_any` and `when_all`.

Comment: @ronag: You made me think for a second there that we already had those... yeah, we are missing `then` and its derived ones

Comment: @danijar What's `Data(/* ... */)`? Constructing a temporary object?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`future::wait_for()`](http://cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for). You can specify a timeout, and after that, get a status code.

#### Example:

```
task.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
```

This will return `future_status::ready`, `future_status::deferred` or `future_status::timeout`, so you know the operation's status. You can also specify a timeout of 0 to have the check return <strike>immediately</strike> as soon as possible.

Comment: That is as close as one can get, waiting for _0 seconds_, but it does not guarantee it will not block...

Comment: "Blocks until specified timeout_duration has elapsed or the result becomes available, whichever comes first." To me, this sounds like what he wanted?

Comment: Keep reading... _"This function may block for longer than timeout_duration due to scheduling or resource contention delays."_

Comment: Yes - I've seen that. But that merely means that it might block a bit longer than your timeout. So if the operation takes 2 minutes, and you specify a timeout of 500 ms, it will return **much** earlier than 2 minutes. So if you have a lot of threads the OS's scheduler might not immediately switch back to you, which may result in a slightly longer timeout. But it will not block until the asynchronous operation's termination.

Comment: The point is that it **may** _block_, even when specified to wait for 0 seconds. It _may not_ return immediately as you claim in your answer. And you want to avoid blocking and a context/thread switch if all you want to know is if the future is ready.

Comment: Well ok, I have to agree that the wording from your edit is better/clearer.

Comment: @K-ballo: Testing whether the future is ready is inherently an operation on shared state, and as such it requires the acquisition of the lock inside the shared state, which **may** block. That is, the wording in the standard does not mean that it has any other costs besides the obvious, and you cannot get anything better than what `wait_for` does.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yep, I opened with "That is as close as one can get"... May an implementation use an atomic boolean to flag the ready state? I wonder how _Boost_ does it and what guarantees it provides...

Comment: @K-ballo: That would be quality of implementation, and in such an implementation I would expect `wait_for` to return without blocking if the period is 0, or `wait_until` to return without blocking if the time is in the past.

Comment: @K-ballo: Which guarantees? Note that Boost's implementation acquires a lock to test for readiness.

Comment: @GManNickG: Well, that pretty much clears my doubts... and I'm starting to like the fact that the standard does not include `is_ready` then

Comment: @K-ballo: Yup. I think it's possible to have a lock-free implementation, but I think the cost would be hidden dynamic allocation in the future. (But I am in no manner knowledgable on the implementation of futures, having neither attempted to implement on myself nor read an entire implementation.)