# Using std::async() & std::move() to pass data to another thread asynchronously

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, boost

I really want to see how can those two thread functions `RunThread1() & RunThread1()` can run in parallel. That RunThread2() is blocked everytime RunThread1() executes or vice a versa.

I do not want to wait until `future` finishes hence I am using `std::async` along with `std::move`
I am using scoped_lock but I don't see that is a problem here.

I am designing an asynchronous response processing engine, one thread inserts data while another thread reads it from other end.

Any suggestions where that problem might be? Any suggestions on overall design.

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

template<typename R>
bool Is_future_ready(std::future<R> const& f)
{
    return f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready;
}

std::vector<std::future<void>> pending_futures;

class A
{
private:
    boost::thread*                myFunc1Thread;
    boost::thread*                myFunc2Thread;

public:
    A()
    {
        myFunc1Thread = nullptr;
        myFunc2Thread = nullptr;
    }

    void RunThreads();
    void RunThread1();
    void RunThread2();

    void PopulateResponses(vector<string> responses);
    void PopulateResponse(string response);

    struct Record
    {
        char response[128];

        Record(const char* response)
        {
            memset(this->response,0,sizeof(this->response));
            strcpy(this->response, response);
        }

        ~Record()
        {
        }

        Record& operator= (const Record& cmd)
        {
            if(this == &cmd)       // Same object?
            {
                return *this;
            }

            memset(this->response,0,sizeof(this->response));
            strcpy(this->response, cmd.response);
            return *this;
        }
    };

    typedef deque<Record> RecordsQueue;
};

boost::mutex ResponseMutex;

A::RecordsQueue Records;

void A::RunThreads()
{
    myFunc1Thread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&A::RunThread1, this));
    HANDLE threadHandle1 = myFunc1Thread->native_handle();
    SetThreadPriority(threadHandle1, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

    myFunc2Thread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&A::RunThread2, this));
    HANDLE threadHandle2 = myFunc2Thread->native_handle();
    SetThreadPriority(threadHandle2, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);

    myFunc1Thread->join();
    myFunc2Thread->join();
}

void A::PopulateResponse(string response)
{
    Records.push_back(Record(response.c_str()));
}

void A::PopulateResponses(vector<string> responses)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(ResponseMutex);
    std::for_each(responses.begin(), responses.end(), bind1st(mem_fun(&A::PopulateResponse), this));
}

void A::RunThread1()
{
    int i = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        vector<string> responses;
        responses.push_back(to_string(i));
        cout<< "Added: " << to_string(i) << endl;
        i++;

        pending_futures.erase(std::remove_if( pending_futures.begin(), pending_futures.end(), Is_future_ready<void>), pending_futures.end());
        auto f = std::async (std::launch::async, &A::PopulateResponses, this, responses);
        pending_futures.push_back(std::move(f));
    }
}

void A::RunThread2()
{
    while(true)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(ResponseMutex);
        if(!Records.empty())
        {              
            Record res = Records.front();
            cout<< "Processed: " << res.response << endl;

            //some lengthy processing...., let's use sleep() to depict that
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

            Records.pop_front();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.RunThreads();
}
```

Comment: What's your actual problem?  What output are you expecting, what are you observing, what don't you understand about it?  Why are you trying to read `Records.empty()` without holding a lock?  Why busy wait instead of learning about condition variables, or using an existing publisher/consumer implementation?

Comment: I have edited my post, the problem is those 2 threads are not running in parallel. Thread1 is blocked when Thread2 is running. Why is that?

Comment: Output:

Added: 4145
Added: 4146
Added: 4147
Added: 4148
Processed: 22
Processed: 23
Processed: 24
Processed: 25

Comment: "the problem is those 2 threads are not running in parallel." - that's a vague statement: they contest the same mutex so obviously won't be running in parallel for long.  Your output suggests they're both running and `RunThread1` is way ahead of `RunThread2` in pushing strings - unsurprising given the `sleep`.  I still don't understand what you'd expect to be different and why?  You don't have anything to slow `RunThread1` down when it's too far in front (not that you'd necessarily want to)....  Again, a condition variable is the proper way to synchronise this, not a mutex.

Comment: "they contest the same mutex so obviously won't be running in parallel for long." - Where do you see ResponseMutex in RunThread1()?

Comment: Why Thread1() gets stuck when Thread2() sleeps. It shouldn't, Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding futures in a tight loop:

```
void RunThread1() {
    while(true)
    {
        // ... 
        auto f = std::async (std::launch::async, &A::PopulateResponses, this, responses);
        pending_futures.push_back(std::move(f));
    }
}
```

No wonder nothing can keep up with it. The other threads are doing all the locking (thread 1 has no blocking operations, though `Is_future_ready` might force a thread yield, I'm not sure).

Add a sleep somewhere in the loop and you'll find that things are working as expected.

```
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
```

Keep in mind that this is still brittle: it depends on timings to be correct. To be more generally robust, use a proper message/task queue and block the pushing side when the queue is full.

Comment: Thread1() reads data through a socket, it then just passes the data to Thread2() so that Thread2() can write that in to database. Thread2() is running slow for that reason. Thread1() is running at good speed and I don't want to introduce sleep(seconds(1)) in it. I still don't get it why Thread1() gets stuck, it should continue receiving the data through socket while Thread2() is writing the previous data in database.

Comment: @user3924882 Of course you shouldn't introduce sleep! IO delays serve the same purpose (but you didn't show it!) Thread1 doesn't stop, it probably just runs slow as you check a gazillion futures for readiness each time around a tight loop... Fix your design. Use a proper blocking queue, of which there are many available. Live a happy life

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14287174/85371) and specifically the comments, e.g.